# Error Variable CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eestoy trabajando en Codeigniter y tengo un error de variable. Estoy recién familiarizándome con este framework y bueno el código es el siguiente:

**Controller:**

```
public function Todo(){

    $new_id = $this->input->post('id');

    $this->load->model('Model_app');
    $data = $this->Model_app->GetNumeroActual($new_id);

    if (!$data == null) {

      $numero_actual_atencion = $data->numero_actual_atencion;

      $this->load->model('Model_app');
      $data = $this->Model_app->GetLetraServicio($new_id);

      $identificador = $data->identificador;


      $this->load->model('Model_app');
      $data = $this->Model_app->GetModuloAtencionID($new_id,$numero_actual_atencion);

      $moduloatencion_id = $data->moduloatencion_id;

      $this->load->model('Model_app');
      $data = $this->Model_app->GetNumeroModulo($moduloatencion_id);

      $identificador2 = $data->identificador;

      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      echo json_encode(array($numero_actual_atencion,$identificador,$moduloatencion_id,$identificador2));


    }

}
```

El caso es que ingreso un id y este me devuelve un *`numero_actual_atencion`*, Pregunto si la var `$data` es distinta a *`null`* y dentro del if saco el *`numero_actual_atencion`* y lo guardo en una variable, después mando el mismo *id* a otra consulta y guardo lo que me devolvió en la var *`$identificador`*, acto siguiente mando el mismo *id* y el *`numero_actual_atencion`* obtenido y lo guardo en *`&moduloatencion_id`*, mando el *`moduloatencion_id`* y lo retornado lo guardo en la variable *`$identidicador2`* y finalmente aplico

```
echo json_encode(array($numero_actual_atencion,$identificador,$moduloatencion_id,$identificador2));
```

para después poder consumir sus datos.

El error que me arroja es el siguiente:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: controllers/HernannMovil.php
>
> Line Number: 27
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wsatencion/application/controllers/HernannMovil.php
>   Line: 27
>   Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wsatencion/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

Aparentemente el error esta en esta linea:

```
$this->load->model('Model_app');
$data = $this->Model_app>GetModuloAtencionID($new_id,$numero_actual_atencion);
```

creo que no estoy mandando bien la var *`$numero_actual_atencion`*

provocando que no traiga ningún dato de vuelta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es algo complicado poder descifrar tu error con tan poco código, pero te invito a pruebes a comprobar todos los objetos que recoges de tu Base de Datos, es decir:

```
$this->load->model('Model_app');
$data = $this->Model_app->GetNumeroActual($new_id);


////// Aquí compruebas que realmente hayas obtenido 
////// datos de registro de tu anterior consulta (correcto).......
if (!$data == null) {

  $numero_actual_atencion = $data->numero_actual_atencion;

  $this->load->model('Model_app');


  ///// Pero a partir de esta consulta, das por supuesto que 
  ///// recibirás datos (temerario e imprudente) 
  $data = $this->Model_app->GetLetraServicio($new_id);


  ///// Llegado a este punto, $data puede ser NULO y el error es acceder
  ///// a esta variable como si fuese un objeto, lo mismo te ocurre en las
  ///// consultas sucesivas. 
  $identificador = $data->identificador;


  $this->load->model('Model_app');
  $data = $this->Model_app->GetModuloAtencionID($new_id,$numero_actual_atencion);

  $moduloatencion_id = $data->moduloatencion_id;

  $this->load->model('Model_app');
  $data = $this->Model_app->GetNumeroModulo($moduloatencion_id);

  $identificador2 = $data->identificador;

  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(array($numero_actual_atencion,$identificador,$moduloatencion_id,$identificador2));


}
```

Por otro lado, no entiendo por qué cargas el modelo para cada una de las consultas dentro del mismo método.

Yo en un caso así, usaría un `if ( ..... !== NULL` en cada una de las consultas y si la estructura de las tablas de tu Base de Datos te lo permite, lo reduciría a una única consulta construida con JOINS.

Obviamente, todo esto es muy relativo teniendo en cuenta el poco código que muestras en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo el código me da la sensación de que te has dejado un ';' al final de esta instrucción:

```
$moduloatencion_id = $data->$moduloatencion_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas
Probablemente tu error está en que añades otro "$" adicional:

```
 $identificador = $data->$identificador;
```

La forma correcta de acceder es:

```
 $identificador = $data->identificador;
```

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que no encuentra el archivo del modelo, porque lo tanto, no puedes acceder a **Model_app** desde esa línea.

Comprueba que el modelo tenga el mismo nombre físico e interno de la clase.

> Ej: en archivo **Model_app.php** se declare la clase **class Model_app extend**